# RestSharp not deserializing JSON correctly

Tags: c#, json, rest, serialization, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to consume a REST Web Service. I've implemented my own Response object classes to use with automatic Serialization/Deserialization integrated inside RestSharp.

I've also added a mappging with enums that works correctly.

The problem with this class is that when I send a **correct request** I get back a **correct response**, so the Response.Content contains what I expect, but the Deserialization process doesn't work correctly.

**Response.Content**

```
{
    "resultCode": "SUCCESS",
    "hub.sessionId": "95864537-4a92-4fb7-8f6e-7880ce655d86"
}
```

The `ResultCode` property is correct mapped to `ResultCode.SUCCESS` enum value but the `HubSessionId` property is always `null` so it seems like it is not deserialized.

The only possible problem I see is the JSON PropertyName with a '.' in the name. Can it be the problem? Is this related to the new JSON Serializer that isn't Newtonsoft.Json no more? How can I solve it?

**UPDATE**

I found that the Json Attributes are completly ignored, and so also the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`. Therefore I think that the enum mapping is performed automatically by the default Serializer without any attribute.
The problem with "hub.sessionId" property still remains.

**This is my code**

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "resultCode")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ResultCode ResultCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hub.sessionId")]
    public string HubSessionId { get; set; }
}

public enum ResultCode
{
    SUCCESS,
    FAILURE
}

// Executes the request and deserialize the JSON to the corresponding
// Response object type.
private T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient(BaseUrl);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    IRestResponse<T> response = client.Execute<T>(request);

    if (response.ErrorException != null)
    {
        const string message = "Error!";
        throw new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
    }

    return response.Data;
}

public LoginResponse Login()
{
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.Resource = "login";
    request.AddParameter("username", Username, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
    request.AddParameter("password", Password, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
    LoginResponse response = Execute<LoginResponse>(request);
    HubSessionId = response.HubSessionId; // Always null!
    return response;
}
```

Comment: '.' in property name has never been a problem for newtonsoft json. I can say this because oldest and latest both versions work fine with you JSON sample. See fiddle. https://dotnetfiddle.net/i0zmc0 It's using v3.5.x. You can try 8.x as well.

Comment: I'll add some more details about my code.

Comment: `JsonProperty` is a Json.NET attribute. If the serializer isn't Json.NET, the JsonProperty attribute will be ignored. What is the equivalent attribute for the *new* serializer?

Comment: I had the same thought, but: 1) I'm using also `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` attribute that works, since the mapping to my enum class is correct. 2) I tried using `[DeserializeAs(Name = "hub.sessionId")]` attribute as suggested here in the [RestSharp Wiki](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization) but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved using Custom JSON `Serializer` and `Deserializer`, in the case **Newtonsoft's JSON.NET**.
I followed the steps explained in this [article](http://bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer/) by Philipp Wagner.

I also noticed that the serialization of a `Request` using the default `Serializer` didn't work as expected with enums. Instead of serializing the enum string value, it places the enum int value, taken from my enum definition.

With JSON.NET now the serialization and deserialization processes works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the default JSON serializer in RestSharp uses `System.Text.Json`, which is a part of .NET since .NET 6. Therefore, you can now simply use the attribute `JsonPropertyName` to decorate the properties in the DTO class.

Here's an example of a DTO class:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class FacebookAuthResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; } = null!;
    [JsonPropertyName("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; } = null!;
    [JsonPropertyName("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
}
```

And here's an example of how the request is made and the deserialization:

```cs
using RestSharp;

public class FacebookAuthService : IFacebookAuthService
{
    readonly string _clientId;
    readonly string _clientSecret;
    readonly string _redirectUri;
    readonly RestClient _client;

    public FacebookAuthService(string clientId, string clientSecret, string redirectUri)
    {
        _clientId = clientId;
        _clientSecret = clientSecret;
        _redirectUri = redirectUri;
        _client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0");
    }

    public FacebookAuthResponse? GetAccessToken(string code)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("oauth/access_token", Method.Get);
        request.AddParameter("client_id", _clientId);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", _clientSecret);
        request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", _redirectUri);
        request.AddParameter("code", code);
        var response = _client.Execute<FacebookAuthResponse>(request);
        return response.Data;
    }
}
```

Note that the client is just instantiated like this:

```cs
new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0")
```

And the request is made like this in the above code:

```cs
_client.Execute<FacebookAuthResponse>(request);
```

No need to define any custom serializers/deserializers.